# How to reread a few characters from the end of a buffer in C?

Tags: c, file, buffer

I'm using a buffer to temporarily store a certain bytes of data(characters) from a file. I just want to find out whether a particular word is present in the file. Let's say, I'm searching for a word 'Apple' and I'm storing a string from the file into the buffer which has the first half "App" at the end of the buffer and "le" in the next buffer. I just want to make sure that these words are not missed out What can I do to reread a particular length at the end of the buffer. How can I modify the following code?

```
while(feof(fptr)==0){
    char * result;
    char line[100];
    result = fgets( line, sizeof( line ), fptr );

    if ( result == NULL ){
        break;
    }

    line[strcspn( line, "\n" ) ] = '\0';
    token = strtok(line," \t,:;\'\"\?!-_|\\><~@#$%^&*()+{}[].=1234567890");

    while( token != NULL ) {
        printf( " %s\n", token );
        if(strcasecmp(token,word)==0){
            count++; //counts the number of occurrence of the word 
        }
        token = strtok(NULL," \t,:;\'\"\?!-_|\\><~@#$%^&*()+{}[].=1234567890");
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't. Instead only read to a separator which guarantees that you do not read part of what you are looking for.

Comment: You can create two buffers: one for the current line, the other for the previous line. Concatenate them before calling `strtok`. Then copy the current buffer into the old buffer and refill the current buffer. You will need some tweaking to make sure that you do not find the same word twice.

Comment: do not use `strtok` write the simple parser reading the data char by char. This is the most efficient and correct way.

Comment: Aside: instead of using [`feof()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong) to cotrol the loop, use `fgets()` like this: `while((result = fgets(line, sizeof line, fptr)) != NULL)`. You'll have to move `result` and `line` outside the loop for that.

Comment: `strtok` is a nasty function. It mutates the input string, and keeps static state between successive calls. Unless this is a homework assignment, you should really try to avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't necessarily re-read data - if you're reading from a file you can seek, but if you're reading from a pipe then you can't, and you want your program to work with both if possible.

However, you already have that data in the buffer. So you can just use the copy you already have, and move it to the beginning of the buffer:

```
char line[100]; // declare this outside the loop since we need to keep using the same variable

// start it off full of spaces: (or any other symbol you aren't searching for)
memset(line, ' ', 99);
line[99] = '\0';
```

In the loop:

```
// Let's say you're looking for 5 letters ("Apple") so you want a 5-letter overlap.
// Note: we know the buffer has at least 5 valid letters in it, because we always keep that many in it.
memmove(line, line + strlen(line) - 5, 5);
result = fgets( line + 5, sizeof( line ) - 5, fptr );
```

What are we doing?

We're taking the end of the previous buffer and moving it back to the start, then reading more input to fill up the rest of the buffer.

```
Input data: "hello world this is a testerino and here's some more text\n" and we've already read some of it.

Before memmove:
+---------------------------------------------+
|hello world this is a testerino\0djflhashdasa| <- line (the part after the \0 could be gibberish)
+---------------------------------------------+
                           ^^^^^ what we are copying
After memmove:
+---------------------------------------------+
|erino world this is a testerino\0djflhashdasa| <- line
+---------------------------------------------+
 ^^^^^ where we copy it to

After fgets:
+---------------------------------------------+
|erino and here's more text\n\0no\0djlhashdasa| <- line
+---------------------------------------------+
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ what we ask fgets to read
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ what it actually read

And repeat
```

(note: \n and \0 don't actually take up two bytes, I just show them that way for illustration purposes)

Note: This doesn't completely solve the problem! If you're searching for "Apple", and you read "crabApple" and the buffer happens to end just after "Apple", you'd move "Apple" back to the start and then detect it as a word. Also, if you read "Apple" and then the buffer ends, you might detect it twice (before moving and after moving).

Comment: IMO it is dirty workaround not showing the OP the correct direction